# Inaccurate data range in ListPlot

Tags: plotting

I want to have axes x on my `ListPlot` as the range (1,1386), but when I run my code

```
l =  Table[
   Sum[Binomial[k, j]*j^a*(-1)^(k - j), {j, 0, k}], {k, 1, 1386}];
For[i = 0, i < 3, i++, AppendTo[l, 0]]
m = Table[Sum[Binomial[k, j]*j^b*(-1)^(k - j), {j, 0, k}], {k, 1, 1389}];
p = ((2000^1389)/(2000^1386))*(l/m);
t = Table[
  N[Reduce[ 1/(1 + f) <= p[[i]] <= 1 + f && f >= 0 , f], 100], {i, 1, 
   Length[p]}]
t = Cases[t, Except[False]]
tt = t[[All, 2]]

ListPlot[tt,
    Filling -> Top,
    GridLines -> Automatic,
    PlotStyle -> {Red, PointSize[Large]},
    PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, Medium}, DataRange -> {1, 1386}, 
    AxesLabel -> {k, alpha}]
```

the plot has range to 1400 (I mean the last number marked on the axes is 1400)
How can I fix that to have the last marked value as 1386?

Comment: Could you please post `tt` or the function that generates it?

Comment: @IstvánZachar Done. To post `tt` I needed to post another lists of values, so it might be a little messy.

Comment: Your `tt` is taking a long time to generate... you should make a minimal working example instead (since your issue is not related to the data, but to the plotting).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to specify `Ticks` for `ListPlot` (see [this](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Ticks.html)), like

```
...
Ticks -> {Join[Table[n, {n, 1, 1400, 100}], {1386}], Automatic}
....
```

If I understood your code, you attemped to do something like

```
t = Table[n, {n, 1, 200}];
ListPlot[t, PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, Medium}, DataRange -> {1, 1386},
 Ticks -> {Join[Table[n, {n, 1, 1400, 100}], {1386}], Automatic}]
```

[image: list-plot]

Note the interplay between `DataRange` and `Ticks`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Your post is great and very helpful. Thanks!